# Property 'pageEvent' does not exist on type 'NameOfComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I was following the [following tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material7/angular_material7_paginator.htm) (yes it is for Angular 7 and not 10 which I am using),
but I keep on getting this exact error:  `Property 'pageEvent' does not exist on type 'WorkDocumentComponent'.`

My code is just a copy-paste from the supplied tutorial, which makes really weird.

Any clue why that's the case? I am guessing I have to define pageEvent in the .ts file. What does the `pageEvent = $event` do at all? It defines the variable pageEvent as the event or what?

Also if I remove the (page)=... part the code runs smooth, but there's no functionality...

**UPDATE 1**
MRE:

.html file:

```
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox
                    (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()" color="warn">
      </mat-checkbox>

    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)" color="primary"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)" color="warn">

      </mat-checkbox>
      <!--  -->
    </td>
  </ng-container>
 <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nr. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Description Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Beschreibung </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (dblclick)="openTonicUrl()"> {{element.description}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- OB Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ob">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> OB </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ob}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- receiver Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="receiver">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Empfänger </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.receiver}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

.ts file:

```
export interface WorkDocument {
  position: number;
  ob: string;
  description: string;
  receiver: string;
  date: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: WorkDocument[] = [];
export class WorkDocumentComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'position', 'description','ob', 'receiver', 'date'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<WorkDocument>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  selection = new SelectionModel<WorkDocument>(true, []);
  pageEvent: PageEvent;

  constructor(public DataService: GlobalDataService, private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginator fires a [PageEvent](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#PageEvent) using the Output - EventEmitter combination of Angular. By using `pageEvent = $event` convention, you assign the pageEvent variable defined in your component to the event result. So you need to define a propert in your class named pageEvent and type PageEvent like this `pageEvent: PageEvent`.

Comment: I put `pageEvent:PageEvent;` before the constructor, I hope that is correct. But now when I click and select the amount of rows I want to show, the table becomes empty :/ how do I fix this?

Comment: I can help you further, if you can provide a MRE.

Comment: Just did exactly that.

Comment: I can not reproduce your case with the given samples, can you share a stackblitz link please?

Comment: I can't really copy paste my code to StackBlitz, the dataservice provided URL is CORS protected... What rest of the code do you need?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve but if your end goal is to have a table with paginator, material website provides a neat example, might be better to follow official docs. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: The problem is that the example matches my code, but my code doesn't work...

Comment: The page counter is at 0 and if I set the amount per page the table turns blank.